# laravel feature tests with locales

Tags: php, laravel, localization, phpunit

I am new to Laravel and I am having an issue to write a test function that asserts that the HTTP response of my welcome page is 200 knowing that I have EN and FR locales defined, meaning that the test should test both localhost:8000/en and localhost:8000/fr.

This is my **exampletest.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(301);
    }

    public function test_getRedirected_DefaultedEnglish_WelcomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/en');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function test_getRedirected_French_WelcomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/fr');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I don't like writing the code twice for both /en and /fr.

This is my web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::redirect('/', 'en', 301);

Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}', 'where' => ['lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'setlanguage'], function() {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\welcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
});
```

And i have written my localization middleware below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class SetLanguage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        App::setLocale($request->lang);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help on the above. I believe the test should be dynamic.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way around repeating yourself if you want to test multiple locales. But there's no requirement to put each test in a separate method. This may work, but I've never done testing on multiple locales in my applications.

```php
public function provideLocales(): array
{
    return [
        "english" => ["en"],
        "francais" => ["fr"],
    ];
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideLocales
 */
public function testWelcomePage($locale): void
{
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);
    $this->get(route("welcome"))
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

You could take this further and actually check that the localized content is being served correctly.

```php
public function provideLocales(): array
{
    return [
        "english" => ["en", "welcome"],
        "francais" => ["fr", "bienvenue"],
    ];
}

/**
 * @dataProvider provideLocales
 */
public function testWelcomePageContents($locale, $text): void
{
    $this->app->setLocale($locale);
    $this->get(route("welcome"))
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertSeeText($text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will go with the first solution but just add another parameter to route('welcome',app()->getLocale()) and it will work fine. For the second solution, it is okay if you are using two different views (welcome.blade.php and bienvenue.blade.php) but for me i am using the same view file but reading data from json files.

Comment: The second is testing the content shown on the page contains the word "welcome" or "bienvenue" depending on which locale is used, as indicated by the name of the method. `assertViewIs()` is used to check which view is being used to serve the page.